# COUNT returning only one of each

Tags: php, sql

this is my query:

```
"SELECT * FROM data GROUP BY id_s HAVING ( COUNT( id_s ) > 1 )"
```

I have 10x2 entries that shares id_s, and this query only returns the 2nd entry of those that share id_s, what should I do?

Comment: don't use `select *..` when aggregating columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need the `id_s` then use the inner select. To get the complete record do

```
SELECT * FROM data 
where id_s in
(
  SELECT id_s 
  FROM data 
  GROUP BY id_s 
  HAVING COUNT(id_s) > 1
)
```

Your query only works in MySQL. This "feature" is very misleading and throws an error in other DB engines which it should do. If you group, then only select the columns you group by or aggregate the others with functions like sum(), count(), ...